# Options for using ImageMagick from PHP with MySQL blobs?

Tags: php, mysql, image

So my host provides ImageMagick on the server, but no MagickWand or IMagick API for PHP.  I can do operations with the PHP exec command to manipulate images.  But that requires full path file names to work, and I want to pull my images from my MySQL database.  Will I have to have pull them out of the database and put them to a file everytime I want to do this?  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to run the imagemagick process using [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/proc_open) and write/read to/from the created process' stdin/stdout.

To have imagemagick read from stdin, you just give a dash '-' as input file. Specify `/dev/stdout` as the output file. Your call to image magick should look something like:

`convert -scale 150x100 - /dev/stdout`

Use `fwrite` and `fread` on the pipes created by `proc_open` to write input to imagemagick and read output back.

I haven't tried it, but I guess this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If the only ImageMagick available to you can only operate on files (which is how I read your first sentence), then you will indeed have to make files from your MySQL blobs to use ImageMagick on them (and remember to clean things up afterwards). My recommendation might be to switch to a better hosting service, but I assume you have your reasons to stay with that one.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [phMagick](http://www.francodacosta.com/phmagick) ?